# Getting <function main.<locals>.nPrint at 0x02AE0030> when trying to print "for n in variable" Python

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

```
def main():
    import time
    import datetime
    import random


    def nPrint():
        for n in range(1,x):
            print(n)

    def iRan():
        for i in range(0,x):
            xRan = print(nPrint, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            xRan
            time.sleep(1)

    x = int(input('How many times?'))
    iRan()
    xInp = input('Again?(y/n)')

    if xInp == 'y':
        main()
    else:
        exit()

main()
```

I'm pretty new to python, can someone explain why this code can't print from 1 to n?
The output I get every time: `<function main.<locals>.nPrint at 0x02AE0030> 19:05:56`

Comment: `nPrint` is a function, `nPrint()` calls the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your program:
1. nPrint is missing ().
2. Even if you put () it will only keep printing numbers from 0 to a certain range (depends on input) and then output the time.

Therefore I advise you to do the following:

Delete nPrint() and make the program print the variable 'i' instead:

def main():
    import time
    import datetime
    import random

```
def iRan():
    for i in range(0,x):
        xRan = print(i, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        xRan
        time.sleep(1)

x = int(input('How many times?'))
iRan()
xInp = input('Again?(y/n)')

if xInp == 'y':
    main()
else:
    exit()
```

main()

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
xRan = print(nPrint, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Here you try to print `nPrint` while `nPrint` is a function, you should add `()` to call it. Also note that this function is able to print numbers itself, so there is no need to call `print(nPrint())` because this function returns `None` so print will be useless:

```
nPrint()
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Note that there is no need to save `print()` result to `xRan` variable